# How can i display total number of node created by individual user?

Tags: nodes, blocks, users, views

I have created one block by using view, which display author details on each node page, [author details block on each node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107860/how-to-display-view-block-in-node-page)

Here is the link by which the block has been created,now i want to display total number of node  and total number of work viewed created by individual user on the same block which has been created above.

[How to count the node a user has created in a View?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52996/how-to-count-the-node-a-user-has-created-in-a-view)
The way on this link is working fine for displaying all user but its not working after adding **CONTEXTUAL FILTERS
(nodes) Content: Nid | Aggregation setting** by which this block will be able to display on each node.

Please suggest something.

Thanks

Comment: yes, i have done that and that is working fine, but i want it on each node where it display total number node created by the author.

Comment: But when i used **Add a Contextual Filter: Chose "Content: Nid"** then its not responding, after adding filter its displaying total nodes: 1.

Comment: The fact you have tried solutions from the other question does not mean these questions are not duplicates. If you want to ask why your implementation of an answer from older question fails, do it. Describe what you did and how it failed. In your question, not in comment. For now, they are duplicates to me, my vote stays. But don't forget you can edit.

Comment: @molot any solution please suggest